# Celery - how to susbstitute 'None' in logs

Tags: python, django, celery

In Celery's logs there are

`Task blabla.bla.bla[arguments] succeeded in 0.757446050644s: None`

How to replace this `None` with something more meaningfull? I tried to set `return` value in tasks but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you defining your tasks with `ignore_result=True` (or did you set `CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT` to `True`)? If you did, you should try disabling it.

Comment: nope, both no, I'll try to set strong `ignore_result=False`, but it is very doubtfully

Comment: Oh, ok. Did you configure a result backend?

Comment: So, adding `ignore_result=False` gives nothing, but what do you mean with 'backend'? There are almost no celery-related settings in my `settings.py`, at least there are no dictionaries like `CELERY_SMTHNG={...}`, only minimal config, I use `djkombu` also... what else?:)

Comment: Backends are used to store tasks results (see [Keeping results](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#keeping-results)). Using the Django ORM in debug mode, I have the following in my `settings.py`: `INSTALLED_APPS += ('kombu.transport.django',); BROKER_URL = 'django://'; CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'djcelery.backends.database.DatabaseBackend'` (in prod I use Redis).

Comment: I have: `INSTALLED_APPS += ('djcelery', 'djkombu')`, `import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()` at the very beginning of file, `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = "djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler"
BROKER_BACKEND = "djkombu.transport.DatabaseTransport"` plus some `CELERY_IMPORTS` filled with files where I have my celery `@task`s, that's all:)
`

Comment: Could you try adding a result backend like `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'djcelery.backends.database.DatabaseBackend'` then?

Comment: so, I did not add it, but now, after this days - everything works just like I need... looks like I had to restart all the processes (`./ manage.py runserver / nginx` and `./manage.py shell`), thank a lot anyway:)

Comment: By any chance, did you forget to return result from the task and not the underlying function ? I had a function foo and a task bar. The function foo did return a result but I forgot to return the result from the task bar.